# Unable to fetch data in Json format from MongoDb using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using Node.Js and MongoDb as a back-end service. I have 4 documents in my collection and each document has 3 fields named `_id`, `Name` and `Image`. All I want is to fetch data in Json format.

But it is showing error like:

[image: Error image]

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');    
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); 

app.post('/offers',(req, res) => {

     MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {           
        if(err) throw err;
        var obj = req.body.place;
        var dbo = db.db('Tiffino_db');

        dbo.collection("Offers")
            .find({ Name: obj },{ projection: { _id: 0 } })
            .toArray((err, result) => {
                 result.forEach((err, doc) => {
                     if (err) {
                         console.log("Error:", +err);
                     }
                     else { 
                        res.json({'Name':doc.Name},{'Image':doc.Image});
                    }
                });
            });
    });
});
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in above code.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Do you have any idea which line produces the error?

Comment: @Digvijay I think you mean `console.log("Error:", err)` the prefix operator is giving you the `NaN`. Once you fix that I expect it will just print your documents because `forEach` doesn't take an error as its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help you

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   if (err) throw err;
   var dbo = db.db("mydb");
   dbo.collection("Offers").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log(result);
      db.close();
   });
});
```

Comment: your code is working fine but how can i get  Name and Image field out of result as a json object.

Comment: you can iterate on the length of **result**

Comment: for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){
 console.log(result[i].name)
console.log(result[i]._id)
}

Comment: This is working fine but it is fetching only one row.I have multiple documents with the same name so it should fetch all those documents.

Comment: @Digvijay can you share your code, how you are iterating the rows?

Comment: coll.find({Name:obj},{projection:{_id:0}}).toArray((err,result) => { if(err){
                          console.log("Error:".red, +err);
                         }
                         else{

                          for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){ 
                          
                            res.send({'Name':result[i].Name}); 
                          }
                          db.close();
                         }   
                  });

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this page http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find, the main difference is your use of the forEach function which should look like this :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); 

app.post('/offers',(req, res) => {

     MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {           
        if(err) throw err;
        var obj = req.body.place;
        var dbo = db.db('Tiffino_db');

        dbo.collection("Offers")
            .find({ Name: obj },{ projection: { _id: 0 } })
            .toArray((err, result) => {
                 result.forEach((doc) => { // <-- removed err in forEach's fat arrow
                     if (err) {
                         console.log("Error:", +err);
                     }
                     else { 
                        res.json({'Name':doc.Name},{'Image':doc.Image});
                    }
                });
            });
    });
});
```

Not sure how it would produce NaN but forEach's callback first parameter certainly is the actual element in the array. This might hide error from toArray as well.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: yes it is working fine but i want to fetch all record having same name but it is fetching only record.

Answer (score 0):

You need get rid from the "result.forEach" the result is already in array.
res.json({'Name':doc.Name},{'Image':doc.Image}) => res.json(result)